# How to specify the network interface ros2 uses for communication?

Tags: ros, ros2, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch my node, after installing a docker image, I get following warning, luckily it arbitrarily selects the right interface, but how can I specify it to get rid of the warning?
`[od-1] 1614701696.982410 [0]         od: using network interface eno1 (udp/192.168.254.20) selected arbitrarily from: eno1, docker0, br-ab6309382a59, tun0`
I'm using Ros2 build from source master and ros2 branches.
I found: https://answers.ros.org/question/299940/explicitly-constraining-which-network-interfaces-are-used-in-ros2/
and I was wondering if this applies in my case? I didn't find much information and before reading the extensive fast dds api to figure out how to set it, I ask here to make sure, this would even be a solution to my problem and if there is a new(set it directly by ros2) way to specify the network instead of going and fiddling with the default implementation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373132/how-to-specify-the-network-interface-ros2-uses-for-communication?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a file like this: example.xml and launch the node with following command: `FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=<path/to/xml/example.xml> RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp ros2 launch my_node file.launch`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <transport_descriptors>
        <transport_descriptor>
            <transport_id>CustomUDPTransport</transport_id>
            <type>UDPv4</type>
            <interfaceWhiteList>
                <address>enp3s0</address>
            </interfaceWhiteList>
        </transport_descriptor>
    </transport_descriptors>
    <participant profile_name="CustomUDPTransportParticipant">
        <rtps>
            <userTransports>
                <transport_id>CustomUDPTransport</transport_id>
            </userTransports>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omair50](https://answers.ros.org/users/74311/omair50/) on 2021-05-10**:
Hi, I tried your proposed solution, but it does not not send the data over the specified interface. Do we have to change something inside the pub/sub code?
https://fast-rtps.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/transport/whitelist.html

**Comment by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on 2021-08-25**:
No, that was all that was needed for me

**Comment by [antonyramsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/96119/antonyramsy/) on 2022-02-05**:
thanks very very much. I was using docker with ros2 (Ardupilot's SITL + mavros2 + ros2 in docker and my own script from the host! ) and I was really really confused by its behavior. I could send my messages with rqt and command line but my scripts wouldn't work.
it took me about 2-3 days until I realized it's not my script's bug, QoS mismatch, docker's network bad config, mavros/mavlink bad behavior, etc! and suddenly solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

According to [fastrtps docs on whitelists](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/transport/whitelist.html) you can whitelist either via ip address or interface. From the docs:

Interface whitelist filled with IP address (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <transport_descriptors>
        <transport_descriptor>
            <transport_id>CustomTcpTransportWhitelistAddress</transport_id>
            <type>TCPv4</type>
            <interfaceWhiteList>
                <address>127.0.0.1</address>
            </interfaceWhiteList>
        </transport_descriptor>
    </transport_descriptors>

    <participant profile_name="CustomTcpTransportWhitelistAddressParticipant">
        <rtps>
            <useBuiltinTransports>false</useBuiltinTransports>
            <userTransports>
                <transport_id>CustomTcpTransportWhitelistAddress</transport_id>
            </userTransports>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

Interface whitelist filled with interface names (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <transport_descriptors>
        <transport_descriptor>
            <transport_id>CustomTcpTransportWhitelistName</transport_id>
            <type>TCPv4</type>
            <interfaceWhiteList>
                <interface>lo</interface>
            </interfaceWhiteList>
        </transport_descriptor>
    </transport_descriptors>

    <participant profile_name="CustomTcpTransportWhitelistNameParticipant">
        <rtps>
            <useBuiltinTransports>false</useBuiltinTransports>
            <userTransports>
                <transport_id>CustomTcpTransportWhitelistName</transport_id>
            </userTransports>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

Although my suspicion is that fastrtps has recently integrated this feature (see [this PR](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS/pull/3973)) and might not be available in all ros2 releases.

I currently use Foxy which uses the following rmw_fastrtps_cpp versions, where I am unable to specify interfaces by name.

```
~$ ros2 doctor --report | grep rmw_fastrtps_cpp
rmw_fastrtps_cpp                          : required=1.3.2, local=1.3.2
middleware name    : rmw_fastrtps_cpp
```

I noticed that [the mentioned PR](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS/pull/3973) has been part of the v2.13.0 milestone on their github, so maybe this is the problem.

Specifying network by IP address did get my devices connected for now, although I'd prefer to do whitelist per interfaces in the future.