# How to specify ROS2 middleware to publish on usb0 network interface instead of eth0?

Tags: ros2, network

Recently I am working on a ROS2 project that is intended to publish images from a 3d camera. So far locally everything is implemented and works fine. However the sensor is connected to a NXP that runs custom linux. This device besides eth0 network interfaces enables the usb0 network-over-usb interface for network communication. So far I haven't been able to publish topic via this interface and currently I am trying to understand the middle ware implementation part. Would you have any suggestions where to look for the solution?

The opensource repository is based on this project: https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/tof-ros2

Comment: could you mention which ROS 2 middleware implementation you are using on the NXP device and its model, it will allow others to give you a better answer.

Comment: Currently we are building foxy on the NXP, using rwm_dynamic_rtps.
As for NXP we are using this model: https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/eval-adtf3175d-nxz

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/98466/how-to-specify-the-network-interface-ros2-uses-for-communication